# Employer CV browse is missing on careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, cv

Since the update a couple days ago, the browse CV stuff on Careers is missing. There is a link on the front page that says "browse CVs" that links to http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/search, but when I click it, it does a redirect to http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv. There used to be a "browse" button on the menu at the top of all pages, and that is now missing.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment the system is set up in such a way that you're either an employer or a candidate, and you are shown the "file your CV" button or the "Search CVs" button based on your account type.

If you're not logged in, we don't know what type you are, so you see both. If however you are a candidate and click on "search CVs", you will be redirected to the "your CV" area after login, and vice versa. The same redirect happens if you are logged in as a candidate and click on the "browse CVs" button (it might not be a bad idea to take that out if we know you are a candidate...).

If you're a new user, and just signed up, until you've either started searching CVs or filed a CV, both sections are accessible. But as soon as you do one or the other you will be cast into either an employer or a candidate role.

For existing accounts there should be no ambiguity, but for new accounts, if in looking around the site we mistakenly cast you in the wrong role, email us at careers@stackoverflow.com and we'll be able to fix that.

Comment: +1, and welcome to the weird and wonderful world of Meta.

Comment: Why differentiate the two roles? Over time, someone is likely to change from a candidate to an employer (or vice-versa). As-is, this requires making a totally new account. In my case, my own account must have been marked as a candidate. Then when I tried to make a new one, I probably was on a candidate page, and so my new account also became a candidate, leading me to think it's broken.

Comment: I'll also suggest that the link should NOT do a redirect, because it's totally confusing. 1) If I'm logged in, and in a candidate role, the home page shouldn't show a "browse CVs" button that links to the wrong place. 2) If I do manage to get to that URL, it should show me a message saying I'm a candidate and can't be an employer.

Comment: @gregmac: We are planning to lift this differentiation in the future and allow you to do both (I'm not sure why this was done in the first place) and for now will take the button of the homepage. I like your suggestion of not redirecting, and will look into that.

Comment: @korneel this was primarily done to prevent users from scraping our internal database by being both an "employer" and a "candidate". Beware.